# How to match a value starting with '/' or '//' in shell script using regex?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, scripting, sh

In my shell script I am trying to match a value using regex. I have two conditions 1) if the value starts with single forward slash and 2) when it starts with double forward slash.

In my hive hql script I use the following and it works for the conditions I mentioned above:

1) "^/{1}[^/]$"

2) "^/{2}"

But I am unable to get it working in shell script. Below is the code for the single forward slash match.

```
value=/ABCD222
RGX="^/{1}[^/]$"
if [[ $value =~ $RGX ]]; then
  echo success
else
  echo failure
fi
```

I even tried using slash twice but it doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's examine your regex `^/{1}[^/]$`:

`^` start of line
`/{1}` slash exactly once
`[^/]` any character except slash exactly once
`$` end of line

So your regex matches only lines with `exactly` 2 characters (excluding nl).

To match all lines containg *at least* 2 characters, starting with a single slash, simply omit `$`. The simplest way to achieve this is `^/[^/]`. You can omit `{1}`, is default.

Comment: Thanks!! I figured that now. The actual code was taking a substring of the first two characters after which the regex was applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
value='/ABCD222'
rgx = '^/[^/]*$'

if [ $value =~ $rgx ]; then
  echo success
else
  echo failure
fi
```